# Deleting lots of files

Tags: shell, command-line, find, io

I accidentally created 8 million files and every time I'm trying to delete them the server almost dies because of the rm process eating all disk IO (the server is remote without console).

Should something like this work i.e. invoking ionice?

```
sudo find /var/lib/php5/ -type f -exec ionice -c3 rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: What's the `-c3` parameter?

Comment: @badp `ionice -c3` basically set it to the lowest IO priority.

Comment: except `unlink` is a system call which has essentially no IO activity. The file system implements the actual IO needed to complete an unlink so I don't know if ionice can help here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would do it like this...

```
sudo ionice -c3 find /var/lib/php5/ -type f -exec  rm -f '{}' +
```

the `+` is more xargs like (I think), and thus more efficient at very large numbers of files. putting ionice on the whole command should make every sub command also ioniced, as well as the search itself. Have you tried this?

you could also make it [really nice](http://www.xenoterracide.com/2008/04/really-nice.html) `nice -n 19 ionice -c 3 programname` though it shouldn't be necessary.

or taking a cue from [@alex](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1946/alex) you could

```
ionice -c3 find /var/lib/php5/ -type f -delete
```

Comment: Even better use `find`'s `-delete` instead of spawning `rm`s.

Comment: @alex right, I completely forgot about it. I was simply tuning his, instead of thinking of that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
import os
os.nice(19)
dir = "/var/lib/php5/"
bad_files = [os.join(dir, file) for file in os.listdir(dir)
                     if is_bad(os.join(dir, file))]
for junk in bad_files:
  os.unlink(junk)
  time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: looks like python?

Comment: @phunehehe Bingo!

Comment: yeah I have just started learning python, but don't you think you should include some instruction on how to run this script?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too silly.

What about deleting the whole directory structure?

```
find /var/lib/php5 -type d -print > /tmp/directories
rm -r /var/lib/php5
cat /tmp/directories | xargs mkdir
```

Comment: That will not be any more efficient, it still requires calling `unlink()` on every file.